# ERROR 1001 (45000) old data received in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert data to MySQL table, but without inserting it I got the error like
`ERROR 1001 (45000) old data received` error. But when I am trying to insert into with a different date it is inserted

Suppose my table schema is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `sdp_transaction` (
  `correlation_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `time_stamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `sp_id` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sp_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_id` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_state` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
);
```

I tried with following queries

query #1

```
INSERT INTO sdp_transaction VALUES ('921102201000000000','2022-03-22 00:09:02','SPP_000036','himuarif','APP_000165','loves','live');
```

query #2

```
INSERT INTO sdp_transaction VALUES ('921102201000000000','2022-03-22 16:09:02','SPP_000036','himuarif','APP_000165','loves','live');
```

The 1st query is not inserted, it came out mentioned error above, but the 2nd query is inserted without an error. Defining columns names to INSERT query also not working. With some experiments, I realise that data is not inserted before the data of 2022-03-22 at 15:00:00. But after that time records are inserted without any error. As I remember I applied RENAME query for the column app_state before its name was col1.

What is actually happed, Why this kind of error is coming ??? How to solve it ???

Comment: Hi, what `mysql` version are you using? I made a demo for your reference. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d23145632eade15fbc5bd724a1bbab3d I use `mysql v.8.0`

Comment: Normally I would suspect daylight standard time but I see your university is in Sri Lanka which does not observe DST. IRAN though did DST on 2022-03-22 are you somehow working to Iran time?

Comment: Please run `SELECT @@global.time_zone;`  `SELECT @@system_time_zone;` and `SELECT VERSION();` and show the outputs in your question.

Comment: @fonz I saw your demo, according to my knowledge also it should be inserted. Also, be noted this is not happed to my local machine, it happed in the LIVE environment.

Comment: @Kendle SELECT @@global.time_zone --> SYSTEM, SELECT @@system_time_zone --> +06, SELECT VERSION() --> 8.0.13 This is taken form the LIVE servers

Comment: @Rasika Weragoda are the time zones quoted for LIVE? if not please add them too.

Comment: @P.Salmon the mentioned values are in LIVE

Comment: Finally, Our teammates realized that the table's partitions were somehow corrupted. Thank for All your help